# Best / Most Efficient averages of multi-dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a application that has the following the following:

Each month, an API returns a series of values depending on the data, so something like (These are updated everyday so the results are cached)

```
$data = array(

   array("2016-02-03" => 3", "2016-02-04" => 4", "2016-02-05" => 1"),
   array("2016-02-03" => 1", "2016-02-04" => 2", "2016-02-05" => 3"),
   array("2016-02-03" => 60", "2016-02-04" => 18", "2016-02-05" => 3"),

);
```

What I am therefore trying to achieve is that the algorithm will take the first key ("2016-02-03") then iterate through all of the sub arrays and find the values for this key and then sums them up and calculates the average, finally add this to another array. This will continue until there are no more keys left.

The problem is, I could have a huge foreach loop and do it that way, but the problem is, there are over 40 values and all contain around 30 days worth of data so this would be inefficient.

Is there an alternative to solving this problem? One that won't be intensive and slow?

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine the sulotion is to run the server for as long as it takes. I also suggest that after each date match you add the value to your new array and unset the index to reduce memory and the time needed to loop through everything.

In your new array you can have the syntax:

```
[ "Year-month-day" => [...] ]
```

Where the dots will be all the values.